# Incompatible type in custom QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have the following code that returns an "assigning to 'GraphicsPixmapItem *' from incompatible type 'GraphicsPixmapItem *' compiler error.

Can somebody help me?

Here is the code:

The main file:

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    GraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 318, 458);
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.setBackgroundBrush(QPixmap(":/images/background.jpg"));
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The custom GraphicsScene header:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsScene(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *Logo;
};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

The custom GraphicsScene cpp:

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"

GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QWidget *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene()
{
    QPixmap Contactinfo(":/images/ScreenContacts.png");
    GraphicsPixmapItem *buf = new GraphicsPixmapItem;
    buf = addPixmap(Contactinfo);
    buf->setPos(0, 40);
    buf->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
}
```

the custom QGraphicsPixmapItem header:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
#define GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class GraphicsPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
  GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);

protected:
     QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);
};

#endif // GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
```

and finally the custom QGraphicsPixmapItem cpp:

```
#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

GraphicsPixmapItem::GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent, QGraphicsScene *scene)
  : QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent, scene)
{
}

#include <QDebug>
QVariant GraphicsPixmapItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    qDebug() << "itemChange Triggered";
    if (change == ItemPositionChange) {
            qDebug() << "Position changed";
        }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGraphicsScene::addPixmap() returns a QGraphicsPixmapItem. You're trying to assign a pointer to QGraphicsPixmapItem to a pointer to GraphicsPixmapItem, which are different types.

Also note that by assigning to buf using new, and then calling `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap()`, you're creating two distinct objects, namely one GraphicsPixmapItem (from `new`) and one QGraphicsPixmap (from `addPixmap`) item.

What you probably want is something like `buf->setPixmap(Contactinfo);` and then call  `addItem(buf);` from your scene constructor, and eliminate the `addPixmap()` call.